# Search - Only search for post meta field

Tags: search

I know there are a lot of good plugins which extend the wordpress search but I want to do the opposite. I want the search only to return posts which have a certain value in a certain post meta field.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure this is what you want (because it is so ... easy), but all you need to do is add the following inputs to your search form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="meta_key" name="meta_key" value="YOUR-META-KEY">
<input type="hidden" id="meta_value" name="meta_value" value="YOUR-META-VALUE">
```

Or, if you want to trigger the search *by hand*, do it like so:

```
$search = new WP_Query(array(
    's' => 'YOUR-KEYWORD(S)',
    'meta_key' => 'YOUR-META-KEY',
    'meta_value' => 'YOUR-META-VALUE'
));
```

**// EDIT**
If you're dealing with a more complex setup, you might want to use a `meta_query`:

```
$search = new WP_Query(array(
    's' => 'YOUR-KEYWORD(S)',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'YOUR-META-KEY',
        'value' => 'YOUR-META-VALUE'
    )
));
```

Or even

```
$search = new WP_Query(array(
    's' => 'YOUR-KEYWORD(S)',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'YOUR-FIRST-META-KEY',
            'value' => 'YOUR-FIRST-META-VALUE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'YOUR-SECOND-META-KEY',
            'value' => 'YOUR-SECOND-META-VALUE'
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: It seems easy but I can't leave out the s parameter. I really only want results with the right meta_value for a specific meta_key but when I leave out the s param I get no results. If I keep it but make it blank -> no results. If I assign the same value I assign to my meta value I get results but from my meta_value and results in the post text. It's nice that I can add the meta query but wordpress will still look for matches in the post text because of 's'